# How to share a sub folder, yet allow the user to see the folder hierarchy upto this subfolder?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have following folder structure:

```
Parent folders
  Level1 sub folders
     Level2 sub folders
```

Here are my observations on Link sharing:

1. Say I share 2 of the Level2 sub folders. Now when user opens the email link for the first folder, then he can only see that Level2 subfolder. User has to click on the other link to be able to see both the subfolders that are shared with him.

**Question 1**: There seems to be no way of showing the user everything that's shared with him. Is there?

2. Link sharing a sub folder causes wierd SharePoint permission model behaviour. That is - the sub folder no longer inherits permissions from parent folder, and is converted to unique permission based, so existing users (whose permission is based on inheritance from parent folder) complain that they cannot access the sub folder any more (because unique permission breaks inheritance).
3. Another side effect of Link sharing a folder is that - suppose with the goal of showing user the hierarchy of parent folders I share the parent folder with the user, then at sub folder level if I break inheritance, then the user is still able to see the sub folder because breaking of inheritance doesn't apply to users having access to parent folder via link sharing.
4. Link sharing is based on passcode, it doesn't add the user into the AD, and doesn't allow user to be added into advanced sharing. Whereas advanced sharing requires the user to be invited into the AD, and then I can either use link sharing or advanced sharing with this user.

**Question 2**: Given the above findings, is there any way to share the sub folder with a user, yet allow the user to view the folder hierarchy from the parent to the sub folder that the user has access to?

One way I'm thinking is to ditch link sharing and use AD guest user approach and give the end user permission at the parent folder level. Thus he can see parent and all subfolder's. Suppose I want user to see only 1 subfolder (Sub folder 1), then I can break the inheritance on all subfolders and explicitly assign user with access to sub folder 1.

For any subsequent users (say another user requires access to sub folder 2) then I need to add user at parent folder and sub folder 2.

The only negative aspect of this approach is that when a new sub folder or file is created under the parent folder, then the user 1 and user 2 will have access to that file/folder, and I will need to break the inheritance on them. This is difficult to manage.

Is there a better way to show the user the hierarchy from parent level upto the sub folder level with minimum maintenance required?